# C# WPF Project cannot call F# library

Tags: .net, wpf, f#

Recently I took a 2 week hiatus from my current project to write a decent sized file parser and a numerical error checker.  I decided to write them in F# for kicks and giggles. Fantastic decision.

The older version of the program written in VB was over 1000 lines; I managed it in 170 in F#.  Awesome.

I'm back on my current project now and want to incorporate an F# lib to do some parsing and maybe writing/reading an XML save file.  But I cannot seem to figure out how to call an F# library from a C# WPF application for the life of me.

I'm using Microsoft Visual 2010 Professional, here's what I've attempted thus far referencing this article: http://www.devjoy.com/2013/02/c-to-f-interop-sharing-a-domain-model/ 
and a couple SO posts:

1. Create a WPF project.
2. Added an F# library project to the solution.
3. Added a reference to the F# library to C# project via:  Right click project file in     SolutionExplorer, click 'Add Reference', selected 'MyFSharpLib' from projects tab and click Add.
4. I then added some test code to the default F# file module1.fs:

   ```
   module Module1

   let Add a b = a + b
   ```
5. And tried to call it from C#:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Documents;
   using System.Windows.Input;
   using System.Windows.Media;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
   using System.Windows.Navigation;
   using System.Windows.Shapes;

   namespace WpfApplication2
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   // Call F# library
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       int a = Module1.Add(1, 2);
   }
   }
   }
   ```

This results in an error saying:  "The name 'Module1' does not exist in the current context."

I think the problem is with the assemblies.  I noticed in a couple code samples I've seen have `using Microsoft.FSharp.Core`.  Is this the source of my grief?  I tried adding it and couldn't find it under the .NET tab.

This is driving me crazy, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you build the library??

Comment: Durr moment of the year. Thanks buddy.

Comment: I guess there is some assumptions here.  You did create the F# DLL and made a reference to it, right?

Comment: Yes.  The issue was I had to build the library and THEN build the C# project. Feel like an idiot. Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to the idiot club, here's your card.  I'll take your dues later - I'm the president.

Comment: 100k for private university clearly have not helped ;)

Comment: @SteelNation Don't worry about it -- IIRC the C# compiler still provides IntelliSense to other projects in the solution which reference it, without having to actually build the C# project. The F# compiler (actually, VS language service) only updates the IntelliSense it provides to referencing projects when the project is actually compiled without errors.

Comment: @JackP. Ahhhh so IntelliSense doesn't know the libs there till its compiled. You know you've been developing .NET too often when IntelliSense not popping up instantly makes you worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you found the answer already -- building the F# project -- but I'm going to provide an answer (for posterity) to a problem which would have almost the exact same symptoms, but a different underlying cause.

If you use your example F# code exactly as provided, that is, a module with a simple name (without a namespace), it's important to know that you need to use the `global` keyword when accessing the F# module from C#. For example, this is how you'd have to call the `Add` function you defined from C#:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = global::MyModule.Add(1, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you have a specific reason not to, it's usually just a better idea to use a namespace with your module, e.g., `module MyNamespace.Module1`.

Comment: Really? Seamed to work fine for me. Is it when you have multiple modules that issues will arise?

Comment: @SteelNation No, I created a sample solution with two projects -- one with the exact F# code you provided and one with the C# code from my answer (though I trimmed off the `using` declarations). I wasn't able to call MyModule.Add until I added the `global` keyword. It's possible this is something that changed between VS2010 and VS2012 (i.e., F# 2.0 and 3.0).