# Unable to call F# Extension in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, f#, extension-methods

**Solved: IntelliSense just doesn't show the Extension!**

Lets say we got the following extension method in F#:

```
[<Extension>]
module Extension =
    [<Extension>]
    let Increment(value : System.Int32) = value + 1
```

In C# I can call it like this way:

```
x.Increment(); //Result x=1
```

But the equivalent VB code to this returns an error, it doesn't find the extension method for the type integer:

```
x.Increment() 'No method called "Increment()" for type Int32
```

While it's possible to call the method by the standard way:

```
Increment(x) 'Works
```

So where is the difference between handling VB and C# on calling F# code, why isn't the VB environment able to resolve the extension methods?

Comment: How do you have `x` declared (on the VB side)?

Comment: I've tried: Dim x As Integer/Int32 or just Dim x = 0I, all three ways doesn't worked for me

Comment: Do you have the proper `Imports` declaration in scope?

Comment: this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702256/f-extensions-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks Liam, I've already read this thread. It doesn't helped me :/

Comment: @Reed Copsey Yes otherwise I won't be able to call Increment() :/

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/mausch/5798633

Comment: Did you put the F# module into a namespace? If not, you may be running into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17113706

Comment: The problem was, that the extension won't be shown by the IntelliSense of Visual Studio. And another problem is that ReSharper wants to remove the Import of the F# library, because it cannot find any relations to it in the VB code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build a regular F# library project

```
namespace A
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
[<Extension>]
module Extension =
    [<Extension>]
    let Increment(value : System.Int32) = value + 1
```

and then refer to this library from VB project

```
Imports A.Extension
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine((1).Increment())
    End Sub
End Module
```

then VB treats F# extension method as expected `<Extension>Public Function Increment() As Integer` and works correctly, giving `2` as output.

**A clean experiment does not indicate any VB-specific idiosyncrasy to F#-defined extension methods**.

Comment: This actually works, but for some reason the intellisense doesn't show the Increment function... Maybe that was the reason which made life hard for me while debugging this. Thank you :)

Comment: @TimKrüger yeah, ReSharper also has issues around this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288188 http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-328715