# Calling an F# Function from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#

I've looked at other instructions and still have no idea how to do this. I have two projects (Calculator in C# and Logic in F#). I added a reference to Logic in Calculator, as well as a reference to FSharp.Core

However when I add the line

```
float result = Logic.start(formula);
```

In my C# project, I get an error saying:

> "The name Logic does not exist in the current context."

There is a module Logic in the logic project, so it should show up right? What am I still missing?

EDIT: Here's the function definition...

```
let start formula =
core (List.ofSeq formula) [] []
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the type is public and method is public. I don't remember off the top of my head what it is that does this in F#. Perhaps post the definition?

Comment: see following question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478531/call-f-code-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot refer from C# just an F# module without any namespace. Do something like this:

```
// F# project
namespace Some
module Logic =
    let start formula =
.....
```

or equivalent

```
// F# project
module Some.Logic
let start formula =
.....
```

and

```
// C# project
.....
Some.Logic.start(formula)
```

and reference F# project from C# project.

**UPDATE**: As [JackP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197411/jack-p) pointed out, the other alternative exists, allowing to avoid using of explicit namespace on F# side altogether.

When in C# you create a class outside of any namespace this class may be referred by prepending its name with `global` contextual keyword followed by `::` operator, which is the way of referencing [default top-level .NET namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx). F# module with a simple name outside of any namespace from reference standpoint is equivalent to one having [`namespace global`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233219.aspx) in the very first line of code. Applying this consideration to your case you may alternatively do:

```
// F# definition
// namespace global is assumed
module Logic
let start formula =
.....

// C# reference
...global::Logic.start(formula)...
```

Gory details about `global::` available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx).

Comment: You *can* call F# modules without a namespace from C# -- you just need to prefix the module/type name with the `global::` qualifier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113512/c-sharp-wpf-project-cannot-call-f-library/17113706#17113706

Comment: @JackP: Thank you, Jack, for pointing to this alternative route. I'll update my answer with covering it too.